# From list of list of dictionaries to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've the following list format (see code snippet) and I want to create a DataFrame to achieve the desired result.

Desired result:`8.00\n4.84\n1.416`     `2.56\n3.104\n3.09`
`1.184\n7.50\n15.00`

````
```
data = [[ {'C': 8, 'G': 1, 'T': 1},
          {'C': 4.84, 'G': 1, 'T': 2},
          {'C': 1.416, 'G': 1, 'T': 3}],
         [{'C': 2.56, 'G': 1, 'T': 1},
          {'C': 3.104, 'G': 1, 'T': 2},
          {'C': 3.09, 'G': 1, 'T': 3}],
         [{'C': 1.184, 'G': 1, 'T': 1},
          {'C': 7.5, 'G': 1, 'T': 2},
          {'C': 15, 'G': 1, 'T': 3}]]
```
````

Comment: ``pd.DataFrame(data).applymap(lambda x:x['C'])``

Comment: @TheMaster Interesting solution! How does this work?

Comment: @TheMaster When I pass to DataFrame I get error; "ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index" . How do I handle this? My apologies..learning along.

Comment: Are you testing with the same `data` provided here?

Comment: @TheMaster I'm testing with fresh data but basically the same in structure. So I get the dataframe output like so : 0 1 2
0 1.170 7.70 17.000
1 1.525 4.38 6.500 ; 0  1  2 are the columns and want to merge them into 1 column to achieve the goal. Thanks

Comment: The data you provided in question works with my code. So, they're not the same in structure. Could you provide a representative sample by editing your question? Or test my code with the sample you've provided in the question?

Comment: Yes you're correct; the one line code solution does return the dataframe split into 3 columns. Can you confirm this? What I need is all 3 data elements in 1 column seperated  by say \n. Hope you can follow my layman explanations. eg 8.000\n4.840\n1.416 as per data set provided

Comment: Try `pd.Series(pd.DataFrame(data).applymap(lambda x:x['C']).astype('str').values.tolist()).str.join("\n")`

Comment: @TheMaster The solution worked  and I'm so excited at the end. Thank you a million
!

Comment: explain how the resulting output is determined.  Are you grouping on rows of 3

Comment: @GoldenLion Yes, grouping in rows of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your data, it looks like you have a list of list of dictionaries. So it just need to be flattened and loaded as a dataframe. Once you have the data in the dataframe, you need to convert the float into 3 decimal place string format, join the list of values and print.

Here's how I will do it:

- **Step 1:** Flatten the data to a normal dictionary with key:value pair
- **Step 2:** Load the key:value pair dictionary into a dataframe

Steps 1 & 2 are accomplished using this list comprehension + DataFrame creation step

```
df = pd.DataFrame([k for klist in data for k in klist])
```

- **Step 3:** Convert the `C` column into a string format with 3 decimal places
- **Step 4:** Concatenate the list as a string using `.join()` while adding
  `'\n'` as separator

Steps 3 & 4 are accomplished using this single line map and join function.

```
c_list = '\n'.join(df.C.map('{:,.3f}'.format).tolist())
```

- **Step 5:** print the data in raw format to get the `\n` as well.

Step 5 is just to print and is another line. I am using repr to give you the `\n` data on the same line.

```
print (repr(c_list))
```

You can do it as follows:

```
data = [[ {'C': 8, 'G': 1, 'T': 1},
          {'C': 4.84, 'G': 1, 'T': 2},
          {'C': 1.416, 'G': 1, 'T': 3}],
         [{'C': 2.56, 'G': 1, 'T': 1},
          {'C': 3.104, 'G': 1, 'T': 2},
          {'C': 3.09, 'G': 1, 'T': 3}],
         [{'C': 1.184, 'G': 1, 'T': 1},
          {'C': 7.5, 'G': 1, 'T': 2},
          {'C': 15, 'G': 1, 'T': 3}]]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([k for klist in data for k in klist])
c_list = '\n'.join(df.C.map('{:,.3f}'.format).tolist())
print (repr(c_list))
```

The output of this will be:

```
'8.000\n4.840\n1.416\n2.560\n3.104\n3.090\n1.184\n7.500\n15.000'
```

To print 3 items one each line, you can do the following:

```
for i in range(0,len(c_list),3):
    print(repr('\n'.join(c_list[i:i+3])))
```

or you can try to print it as:

```
for i in range(0,len(c_list),3):
    print(r'\n'.join(c_list[i:i+3]))
```

The output will be:

```
'8.000\n4.840\n1.416'
'2.560\n3.104\n3.090'
'1.184\n7.500\n15.000'
```

I assume you are asking for this.

I added an extra line to the input dictionary `{'C': 12.5, 'G': 2, 'T': 8}`

The output is as follows:

```
'8.000\n4.840\n1.416'
'2.560\n3.104\n3.090'
'1.184\n7.500\n15.000'
'12.500'
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Just one last part; how would you group the output into a string of '3' like so: '8.000\n4.840\n1.416\n ...line by line.

Comment: what do you mean line by line. As in 8.000 on one line, then 4.840 on the next line, .... ? If so, then do `print (c_list)`

Comment: I mean 3 of the elements in one line , then 3 in next line and so on. sorry for the layman language

Comment: see if my response is what you are looking for. I hope it is.

Comment: Can you re-visit point 'To print 3 items one each line...'; I seem to get a strange result? Thanks

Comment: what is the error you are getting. i ran this again and i still get the results. Not sure what your error is. Please update the question with the error and I can look into it.

Comment: The result looks like this when I run 'the for range...(c_list,3) and the print as above copy & paste   : '1\n.\n1'
'8\n4\n\n'
'7\n.\n5'
'0\n0\n\n'
'1\n5\n.'
'0\n0\n0' ..sorry I'm yet to master updating question. Hope this helps though. Thanks

Comment: nb! I just ran the new set of data values ...but apart nothing else new

Comment: '1.184\n7.500\n15.000  output on step 'print (repr(c_list))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227246/discussion-between-stephen-m-and-joe-ferndz).

Answer (score 2):

1. Convert it to a `numpy` array.
2. `reshape()` to effectively 1D
3. `json_normalize()` to extract the embedded `dict` to columns

```
data = [[ {'C': 8, 'G': 1, 'T': 1},
          {'C': 4.84, 'G': 1, 'T': 2},
          {'C': 1.416, 'G': 1, 'T': 3}],
         [{'C': 2.56, 'G': 1, 'T': 1},
          {'C': 3.104, 'G': 1, 'T': 2},
          {'C': 3.09, 'G': 1, 'T': 3}],
         [{'C': 1.184, 'G': 1, 'T': 1},
          {'C': 7.5, 'G': 1, 'T': 2},
          {'C': 15, 'G': 1, 'T': 3}]]

a = np.array(data)
df = pd.json_normalize(a.reshape(1, a.shape[0]*a.shape[1])[0])
```

### output

```
     C  G  T
 8.000  1  1
 4.840  1  2
 1.416  1  3
 2.560  1  1
 3.104  1  2
 3.090  1  3
 1.184  1  1
 7.500  1  2
15.000  1  3
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. What would be the last part to achieve only 'C' elements in group of three?

Comment: `df = pd.json_normalize(a.reshape(1, a.shape[0]*a.shape[1])[0])["C"]` will give you the series you want

Comment: Almost getting there! I need to get to this: 8.000\n4.840\n1.416 ie 3 across in 'C' only. to achieve the full desired goal. Sorry to ask again Rob :)

Comment: just do `'\n'.join(df.C.map('{:,.3f}'.format).tolist())` to get the value to the desired result

Answer (score 0):

use a generator to create your groupings of three.  I don't handle if the row count is not an interval of 3

```
 data = [[ {'C': 8, 'G': 1, 'T': 1},
      {'C': 4.84, 'G': 1, 'T': 2},
      {'C': 1.416, 'G': 1, 'T': 3}],
     [{'C': 2.56, 'G': 1, 'T': 1},
      {'C': 3.104, 'G': 1, 'T': 2},
      {'C': 3.09, 'G': 1, 'T': 3}],
     [{'C': 1.184, 'G': 1, 'T': 1},
      {'C': 7.5, 'G': 1, 'T': 2},
      {'C': 15, 'G': 1, 'T': 3}]]

 C=[]
 G=[]
 T=[]
 for row in data:
    for item in row:
        C.append(item['C'])
        G.append(item['G'])
        T.append(item['T'])

df=pd.DataFrame({'C':C,'G':G,'T':T})
print(df)

        C  G  T
0   8.000  1  1
1   4.840  1  2
2   1.416  1  3
3   2.560  1  1
4   3.104  1  2
5   3.090  1  3
6   1.184  1  1
7   7.500  1  2
8  15.000  1  3


mylist=df['C']

result=(str(item) for item in mylist)

for i in range(0,len(mylist),3):
    output=r"\n".join([next(result),next(result),next(result)])
    print(output)

8.0\n4.84\n1.416
2.56\n3.104\n3.09
1.184\n7.5\n15.0
```